# My leopard gecko is bleeding under his skin!

Tags: health, reptiles, leopard-geckos, shedding

Recently, I have gotten a leopard gecko. He/she is now about three or four months old. I feed him meal worms and I am hoping to offer crickets for more variety. Recently, I was holding him in attempts to tame him and I noticed a slightly red blotch on the skin of his tail, but I just assumed it was a genetic discoloration and thought noting of it. About a week later, I was doing my routine spot clean in his tank and I noticed blood in his shed box!

By now, I was slightly concerned and scoured the Internet for answers, but found nothing and just concluded that I would wait until his next shed and see if it happens again. Sadly, today I checked his tank and found more blood, less than last time, but still blood. It seems he is bleeding under his skin and then when he sheds the blood comes off that is just a theory though. I promise it is not a problem with the humidity in his shed box, because I've never had a problem with stuck shed on his toes, which apparently is very lucky.

Also, most of the things I read online say that sick leopard geckos are usually lethargic or refuse to eat, but my gecko is none of those. His eyes are clear, he is a great eater and he sheds normally. The only issue I can find that makes no sense to me is that he sleeps in his cold hideout and lounges all night in his warm side, but other than that he is perfectly normal besides the blood thing. Please help me, I can't find any information on the Internet about this happening to anyone else and how to solve it.

Should I go to the vet, which is something I'd like to avoid? Or is this a simple issue I can solve myself? Or should I wait it out?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if you think there is something wrong with your pet you should call your vet for advice,asking the question here is fine but it does not replace advice from a vet.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can attribute that to is stuck shed I'm afraid. Do you have a hygrometer to measure humidity with? Not having stuck shed on toes isn't really the best way of measuring the humidity.

Them sleeping on the cold side and spending the night on the warm side is normal so don't worry about that.

Really though, if it keeps happening I'd say take him to a vet. Consistent bleeding over weeks, even minor, isn't good for anything.